# Tax forms signature requirement violating the 5th Amendment?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, tax-law

I notice that the IRS requires taxpayers to sign their tax forms under a notice that states "I declare under penalty of perjury that ....[the information provided on the form is true]". Obviously there are potential criminal penalties for false statements on a tax form.

So, essentially the IRS is requiring taxpayers to act as a witness against themself by compelling testimony and oaths in potentially criminal matters regarding their finances. This would seem on its face to be a blatant violation of the 5th Amendment to the Constitution which states: "No person...shall be compelled in any criminal case to be a witness against himself".

Obviously the oath requirement is indefensible from a logical point of view, so I am curious (1) what specious pretext is currently being used to legally justify the compulsion of this oath, and (2) what court cases, if any, have tested the constitutionality of taxpayer oaths?

Comment: Also note "willfully failed to file a return" is a criminal act as well.

Comment: In some countries, "willfully failed to file a return" leads to your taxes being estimated. And if you pay, then obviously the estimate was too low, so the next estimate is at least twice the previous one.

Comment: In so far as I'm aware, there is a section on the tax form where you can declare income obtained under 5th amendment privilege (suffice to say, it's read as "I'm not telling you to protect myself against criminal prosecution regarding how I got this money."  You can file legitament income under this if you don't want your finances in the IRS hands.  You can even, if you're feeling bold, list the ski mask and  car off as business expenses.  IRS just wants their cut.).

Comment: Although you may not find this source convincing, the IRS website [cites many cases that have tested this matter:](https://www.irs.gov/privacy-disclosure/the-truth-about-frivolous-tax-arguments-section-i-d-to-e#contentiond4)  *United States v. Sullivan*, 274 U.S. 259, 264 (1927); *Sochia v. Commissioner*, 23 F.3d 941 (5th Cir. 1994);  *United States v. Carlson*, 617 F.2d 518, 523 (9th Cir. 1980); *United States v. Neff*, 615 F.2d 1235, 1241 (9th Cir. 1980); *United States v. Schiff*, 612 F.2d 73, 83 (2d Cir. 1979); *United States v. Brown*, 600 F.2d 248, 252 (10th Cir. 1979); and a few others.

Comment: “Potentially”…. There is a presumption of honesty.  Promising to be truthful is not the same thing as being compelled to testify against yourself once criminal allegations are brought up.

Comment: General tip: i don't think it's helpful to write a question where you presuppose an answer (i.e. that the requirement is unconstitutional), especially when what you presuppose is, shall I say, not mainstream, and when your tone is argumentative.  Some people will silently downvote to signal rejection of your assumptions.  Some people will avoid answering because they don't want to interact with someone with an argumentative attitude.  Others will respond in the same spirit, with an argumentative answer to tell you emphatically just how wrong you are.

Comment: And still others, who agree with your assumptions but for reasons not actually founded in reality, will, in order to reinforce them, write impassioned and sometimes convincing-looking answers based on their theories.  Which you may then be tempted to believe based on *your* own presuppositions.  And those answers in turn will attract others who want to explain how wrong *they* are, and it all becomes a big mess. In my opinion, it's better to write a question in an open-minded tone, not assuming an answer but expressing willingness to learn.

Comment: @NateEldredge The question is not about whether it is consitutional or not. Did you actually read the question? Nowhere in that question do I ask whether the IRS practices are constitutional or not.

Comment: @Cicero Agreed, you don’t ask if the practice is constitutional, you just state that it is a blatant violation of the Constitution.

Comment: @Cicero: Yes, I read the question.  I'll rephrase.  It's a question that apparently is based on assumptions which surely you must know are not widely accepted.  This will tend to lead to the same unhelpful responses that I mentioned above.  In fact, if you are only interested in how courts have ruled, then your personal beliefs about the constitutionality are not even relevant to the question, so why include them at all?

Comment: And what's the point of dismissing all such legal foundation or rulings as "specious" before you have even heard what they are?  It comes across as just gratuitously inflammatory.

Comment: Did you just forget that you asked in January?

Comment: @MichaelHall That was a different question. Did you actually read both questions?

Comment: @NateEldredge Just because an argument is specious doesn't mean I "dismiss" it. If I wasn't interested in knowing what the argument was I wouldn't be asking about it. People serious discuss specious decisions like Wickard v Filburn all the time. Just because a behavior is irrational does not mean it can't be the basis of a legitimate question.

Comment: Yes, of course it was different question.  Similar enough to be deemed a dupe by the majority though.

Comment: Having read  both questions once again, I fail to see any meaningful difference at all between the questions.  They both ask for the justification in case law of the requirement to sign a tax return under penalty of perjury. If you see a difference then I think you should explain it very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The 5th Amendment is not a license to commit fraud. The right not to testify about your past crimes does not mean that you are allowed to be untruthful in the present.